# Creating drop menus inside `sidebar-nav`

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please hvae a look at the below code

```
<div id="main-sidebar-wrapper" style="margin-top:50px; width:150px;">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <!--  <li> <a href="#"> Face Sheet</a> </li> -->
      <li class="li_active"> <a href="Srvlt">History</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="Srvlt">Problems</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="Srvlt">Medications</a> </li>
     <!-- <li> <a href="#">Immunizations</a> </li> -->
      <li  >  <a href="Srvlt">Allergies</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="Srvlt">Vitals</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="Srvlt">Examinations</a> </li>
      <li  > <a href="Srvlt">Counseling</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="Srvlt">Demographics</a> </li>
      <hr>
      <li>Documents Upload
          <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="Srvlt">E.C.G</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li> 
    <!--  <li> <a href="#">Documents</a> </li> -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here, the `Documents Upload` section, I want it to be a drop-up menu or drop-right side menu. How can I do this?

Comment: I think we'll need your existing CSS showing what you have tried...with your rep I would assume that this is just an oversight.

Comment: @Paulie_D: ahh, sorry. I am a developer so I know little about designing. which CSS file you require?

Comment: We need to see what you have done to do this yourself. If you can make a demo : see  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you have tried and didn't get to work you are likely to get more help. At the moment, you just seem to be asking "Code it for me" and that's nopt what SO is for.

Comment: @Paulie_D: This is bootstrap.

Comment: I'm aware of that....what have **you** done to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

.navbar
{
 max-width:300px;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
} 

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-left,
.navbar-right,
.navbar-header
{float:none !important;}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {left:0;right:auto;}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Jquery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccpm2sbb/).

Need to do some change in

`<li>Documents Upload
          <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="Srvlt">E.C.G</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>`

I have made required changes. Please go through the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to how the dropdown menus work on mobile, may help.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar-fixed {
  padding: 5px 18px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 175px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.sidebar-fixed #drop-one {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}
.sidebar-fixed #drop-one > li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.sidebar-fixed #drop-one > li >a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.sidebar-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li > a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-content {
  margin-left: 175px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sidebar-fixed" id="sideNavParent">
  <ul class="sidebar-list">
    <li> <a href="#"> Sidebar</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Something</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#nope" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drop-one"> Something <span class="caret"></span></a>

      <ul id="drop-one" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
        <li> <a href="#"> Something</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Something</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Something</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Something</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Main Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```